# Run a script on boot

Tags: bash, scripts, startup, systemd

I have a script to start a java application automatically.

```
# colors
red='\e[0;31m'
green='\e[0;32m'
yellow='\e[0;33m'
reset='\e[0m'

echoRed() { echo -e "${red}$1${reset}"; }
echoGreen() { echo -e "${green}$1${reset}"; }
echoYellow() { echo -e "${yellow}$1${reset}"; }

# Check whether the application is running.
# The check is pretty simple: open a running pid file and check that the process
# is alive.
isrunning() {
  # Check for running app
  if [ -f "$RUNNING_PID" ]; then
    proc=$(cat $RUNNING_PID);
    if /bin/ps --pid $proc 1>&2 >/dev/null;
    then
      return 0
    fi
  fi
  return 1
}

start() {
  if isrunning; then
    echoYellow "Test App Already Running"
    return 0
  fi

  pushd $APPLICATION_DIR > /dev/null
  nohup java -jar *.jar>test.out 2>test.err &
  echo $! > ${RUNNING_PID}
  popd > /dev/null

  if isrunning; then
    echoGreen "Test Application started"
    exit 0
  else
    echoRed "The Test Application has not started - check log"
    exit 3
  fi
}

restart() {
  echo "Restarting Test Application"
  stop
  start
}

stop() {
  echoYellow "Stopping Test Application"
  if isrunning; then
    kill `cat $RUNNING_PID`
    rm $RUNNING_PID
  fi
}

status() {
  if isrunning; then
    echoGreen "Test Application is running"
  else
    echoRed "Test Application is either stopped or inaccessible"
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
    start
;;

status)
   status
   exit 0
;;

stop)
    if isrunning; then
        stop
        exit 0
    else
        echoRed "Application not running"
        exit 3
    fi
;;

restart)
    stop
    start
;;

*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
```

refer:- https://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-3-init-d-script/

when I run this command using `sudo service test start`, working fine. I want to run this automatically on boot up. I tried to creating `test.service` file on `/etc/systemd/system`. When I run services not starting.

```
[Unit]
Description=Test service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=test
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/test start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write systemd script `test.service` to enable init.d script on boot. If your init.d script is already working fine, you just need to enable your init.d script to run on boot by following commands.

```
sudo update-rc.d test defaults
sudo update-rc.d test enable
```

Comment: True, but the "proper" way would be to write a systemd unit file instead and let systemd handle all those PIDFILE, start/stop/echo, etc. stuff.

Comment: Systemd and upstart are different method. From Ubuntu 16.04 upstart is replaced with systemd.  You can mention java -jar execution command in your systemd script. If will start and stop function according to it.