# Can we write pid into a file which store in systemd?

Tags: startup, systemd

I have a script to start java application on boot time.

```
[Unit]
Description=test Background

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/java -jar /var/www/tset.com/*.jar"
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/test.com

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can we edit this to write pid into a file in specific location?

As an example,

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/java -jar /var/www/test.com/*.jar | echo $! > ${RUNNING_PID}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to run java directly rather than running a bash shell that runs java. If you do that you can run the [systemctl show](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemctl.1.html) command to get the PID

```
systemctl show -p MainPID <your service name>
```

assuming of course that your java application doesn't create more processes.

If your service name file ends in .service then you can omit the .service suffix from `<your service name>`

If you run via a bash script then you'll get the pid of the bash shell that's running your java process.

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd approach this problem is this way:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo $$ > /var/run/tset.pid; exec /usr/bin/java -jar /var/www/tset.com/*.jar'
```

There's a couple things that require attention:

- what you're trying to do is to write `.pid` file which contains the PID of the process, and on Linux the ["de facto" location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5173636/3701431) is to put it into `/var/run`
- The `>` operator is for redirecting `stdout` of `echo`, which will be the contents of `$$` or the shell PID.
- Why shell PID ? Well, that's because next thing we're using is `exec` command which [will replace shell process](https://askubuntu.com/a/819960/295286) with your java application. What was PID 1234 representing shell will now be 1234 representing java application.

Such approach, while seems convoluted, is actually more appropriate:

- we know the PID instead of using `ps` or `pgrep` to find it, we don't have to apply complex parsing, nor we have a problem if there's multiple instances of the application running already ( which shouldn't be the case if you're using a systemd service to start it, but there's no harm in accounting for a possibility of that as well )
- and with `exec` resources won't be wasted for starting multiple processes. When you have something like `bash -c '/usr/bin/java -jar myapp.jar & pgrep -f myapp.jar > /var/run/myapp.pid '` that's 3 processes. In the above command suggested - we have one process replacing another.

Of course, this is just an example. Adjust how necessary to your case, and `/var/run/tset.pid` is chosen here just as an example - naming is up to you as well as location of the file, though I'd recommend using `/var/run` for consistency with other applications.

Side note:

The `| echo $! > ${RUNNING_PID}"` part wouldn't be appropriate for at least one reason: `${RUNNING_PID}` is a variable, however it is not declared anywhere, so it would be a replaced by plank in shell. `|` is pointless - `stdout` of java application is connected to `stdin` of `echo` which in case where you want output of application sent to another application is appropriate, but echo does not read `stdin` - i.e. here it is pointless.

Of course, if the application itself ( i.e. the java application ) forks - i.e creates - another process the `$$` won't help much, though to be perfectly fair if the application does indeed create multiple forks then it probably should be the job of the application itself to create and manage the `.pid` file and report main process pid.

Comment: Can we use another method insted of this? As a example `java -jar` script is somewhere else and start that script using systemd ?

Comment: @Janith That depends on the details, though I'd say `exec`  way is better. You say you have a script file somewhere. Well, is that a shell script ? If that's so, it could be edited to perform pretty much same function as show in the answer. Again, everything depends on the details - I can't give any concrete suggestions without knowing them.

Comment: Yes it is a shell script. I have a shell script to start and write pid into a file then kill pid. Can I run using systemd service.

Comment: @Janith  Sure, starting things via systemd is perfectly fine. However, have you considered using `systemd stop servicename` instead of pid file ? This may be a more appropriate mechanism for manually stopping a service. Typically .pid files are intended for ensuring there exists only one instance of a process/application.   I'd recommend either editing your question with more details, or asking a new question which describes the situation exactly of what you want to do with the script. Again, personally I'd just the method I described in this answer. It's appropriate for scripts,too

Comment: I have asked once. But did not get the appropriate answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100256/run-a-script-on-boot/1100258#1100258. I tried to do that but not worked.

Comment: @Janith I'll try to take a look at the question you linked, see if I can suggest anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87176/discussion-between-janith-and-sergiy-kolodyazhnyy).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$$$$` as systemd escapes `$` with `$` halving their numbers?

Answer (score 1):

systemd leaves your process's pid on enviroment, so you can use it on your script:

```
    [Unit]

    [Service]
    ExecStart=/home/blah/my-process.sh
    ExecStop=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
    PIDFile=/home/blah/blah.pid

    [Install]
```

Comment: Simple, straightforward, useful.